# How to display "parent" companies with count of facilities for given location?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, group-by

I have following database structure (simplified):

```
id | company_name | parent | count_of_facilities | longitude | latitude
1  | Apple        |  0     | 3                   |  ...      | ... 
2  | Apple        |  1     | 3                   |  ...      | ...   
3  | Apple        |  1     | 3                   |  ...      | ... 
4  | Bmw          |  0     | 2                   |  ...      | ... 
5  | Bmw          |  4     | 2                   |  ...      | ... 
6  | HP           |  0     | 5                   |  ...      | ... 
7  | HP           |  6     | 5                   |  ...      | ... 
8  | HP           |  6     | 5                   |  ...      | ... 
9  | HP           |  6     | 5                   |  ...      | ... 
10 | HP           |  6     | 5                   |  ...      | ...
```

What am I trying to do - I am trying to get all companies in a certain location; so far, I am doing it this way:

```
@companies = Company.select('COUNT(id) AS grouped_facilities, 
                             GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS grouped_facilities_ids')
                          .includes(:services)
                          .within(distance, origin: [lat,lng])
                          .where('companies.corporate_hq   = "0""')
                          .group('companies.company_name')
                          .order("companies.count_of_facilities DESC")
```

This solution so far works, but grouping companies based on their name isn't perfect - so I added the column `parent`. The root/parent company has set `0` here and all other "children" ID of the parent company.

If I do a search for a specific location, I want to find how many facilities are in this location and display the parent company + count of the facilities for the given location.

I tried to `group` the companies by `companies.parent`, but this would probably doesn't work, because there's so many companies with `companies.parent = 0`, right?

How could I get the desired output instead of using `group('companies.company_name`)?

**EDIT:**

The desired output for a given location:

```
Apple - 1 facility in this area
BWM - 2 facilities in this area
HP - 2 facilities in this area
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to think about how you can do things more in the Rails way and avoid raw SQL as much as possible.  Writing raw SQL queries should be avoided!  For example, to find all "parent" companies:

```
@companies = Company.where(:parent => 1).within(distance, origin: [lat,long]).where(:corporate_hq => 0)
```

Much cleaner and it allows the query optimizer to do its job and ActiveRecord to abstract things away for you.

This isn't to say that you never need to augment this with actual SQL, but avoid it as much as you can.  It keeps you more portable and allows you to swap out the database backend at some point with minimal fuss.  You've done this to some degree.. Just continue thinking of things set-wise (SQL-ish) and continue adding compound statements.

Comment: Thanks David for the answer. However, using `Company.where(:parent => 1)` will cause that I'll get ONLY "parent" companies in the given location, right? But I need to search also through facilities' locations...

Comment: I'm sorry, based on your question it sure looked like you wanted only parent companies...  The title actually states, "How do I display only parent companies"

Comment: Sorry, I'll change it.